# Using credentials to authenticate users

Tags: java, uber-api

i am new to this api, what i am going through right now is the following:

i can access a user the first time with no problem using the auth code given on the redirect uri when the user authenticates my app, uber suggests to keep/storage credentials to make requests on behalf of any user in the future, buy i can find no way to instantiate a Credential for the user with the token or refresh token, any advice?

i have already tryed something like

```
Credential c = new Credential()
                    .setRefreshToken("MA.CAESEACXatFo4kWUn-v7mUHYbwkiATEoATIBMQ.SF5nzFJ1dnAfBpcleiSy8i_l159Kfx6fIhOCmOOmaxo.blR8m0ly-A1iC330pfMmLZ_EgnANn6NFzb83LOzZ374")
                    .setExpiresInSeconds(2222222222L);
```

but the constructor of Credential is asking for an accesMethod which i cant seem to get by any chance.

Comment: i could give you an answer but in PHP, i already implemented the uber API to my aplication, and it works with the sand box, but is it ok to post an answer in PHP?

Comment: @AndreiFiordean yeah, just post it, maybe it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

so here goes my PHP answer,

FIRST THING **VERY IMPORTANT**: when you register a user, take all that information and store it into a database, so you can use the keys you receive to make requests on behalf that user!

every time you want to make an API request on behalf of a user, you should refresh the bearer token with the refresh token you receive, just like this:

first make a class that will control the functions (some of them will not be used by if you not needed):

```
class uber
{
    private $code = '';
    private $access_token = '';
    private $uber_uid = '';// this is just the id for the 
    //specific user that you should store in the database
    private $refresh_token = '';
    private $expires_in = '';
}
```

after that add some functions within that class: getters and setters for each of the private variables, like this(this is the example for one variable, make them for the rest aswell):

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAccessToken()
{
    return $this->access_token;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $access_token
 */
public function setAccessToken($access_token)
{
    $this->access_token = $access_token;
}
```

Now, if for example want to use a webhook(i recommend that you do), meaning the link you set in your uber account for redirect uri, when you receive a receipt for example, in order to get that receipt you have to refresh the bearer token just like this:

```
function refreshToken($refresh_token)//param is the one you stored in your DB under the name refresh_token
{
    $provider = $this->getProvidersCredentialsFromYourDatabaseForTheSpecificUser();
    // this should return an array
    $client_id = $provider['client_id'];
    $client_secret = $provider['client_secret'];
    $url = 'https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token';
    $fields = array(
        'client_id' => $client_id,
        'client_secret' => $client_secret,
        'grant_type' => "refresh_token",
        'refresh_token' => $refresh_token
    );

    $fields_string = '';
    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }

    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);


    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_decode($result,1);
    $this->setAccessToken($result['access_token']);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

now that your token is refreshed and set in your private you could make a function to retrieve the receipt, for example, just like this:

```
public function getRidesReceipt($receipt_id){

    $url = "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/$receipt_id/receipt";// this is the test environment

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->access_token));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    return json_decode($result,1);

}
```

catching the webhook on the link you set is done like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); //catch the data when posted
$data = json_decode($json,1); // decode it into an array so you could easily read it
```

if you want to check if it is a recept_ready post you can do it like this:

```
if($data['meta']['status'] == 'ready' && $data['event_type'] == 'requests.receipt_ready'){
//add you code of what to happen with that receipt
}
```

i will show you how to make a test on this code on the uber api.

you will need to make 2 more functions for this(**REMEMBER TO REFRESH THE TOKEN BEFORE EVERY REQUEST**):

```
function makeRequest($url, $token){
    $fields = array(
        'start_latitude' => '39.761492',
        'start_longitude' => '-122.423941',
        'end_latitude' => '35.775393',
        'end_longitude' => '-133.417546',
    );
    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '. $token));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
//the below used for seeing something
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(json_decode($result,1));
    echo '</pre>';
//    the above is just for you to see something(should print print a ride id or whatever you requested), you can comment or delete it

    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result,1);
}
```

you can call it like this:

```
makeRequest($url = 'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests', $the_bearer_token_you_just_refreshed);
```

from the information printed when you make the above request take the code and call this function:

```
function modifyRideStatus($url, $status, $token){
    $fields = array(
        'status' => $status,
    );
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '. $token));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!$result)
    {
        echo 'Modified ride to: '. $status;
    }
}
```

and this one you can call like this

```
modifyRideStatus($url = 'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/sandbox/requests/id_of_the_ride_you_requested_and_is_printed_on_the_screen', 'accepted', $the_bearer_token_you_just_refreshed);
```

these are the statuses you will use(call the function 4 times in this order i post here):
1)accepted

2)arriving

3)in_progress

4)completed

when you call the function with the completed status UBER will make a POST on your webhook with the status receipt_ready and you will capture it if you use my code above.

I hope this helps!! if you have questions let me know please!

Comment: Jum, but the problem is i cant make it work with the Uber sdk, i can using http requests on my own but its not the idea, anyway, thanks for the response.